# cypress get element with more than two children

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have this HTML and I want to get the first element with more than 2 children. Alternatively to get the children of the first element themselves

```html
<div class="market-template-2-columns">
  <button type="button" class="market-button">
    <span class="button-title">Option1</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="market-button">
    <span class="button-title">Option2</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="market-template-2-columns">
  <button type="button" class="market-button">
    <span class="button-title">Option1</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="market-button">
    <span class="button-title">Option2</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="market-button">
    <span class="button-title">Option3</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="market-button">
    <span class="button-title">Option4</span>
  </button>
</div>
<div class="market-template-2-columns">
  <button type="button" class="market-button">
    <span class="button-title">Option1</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="market-button">
    <span class="button-title">Option2</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="market-button">
    <span class="button-title">Option3</span>
  </button>
  <button type="button" class="market-button">
    <span class="button-title">Option4</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is this generated html or written this way? If it is written this way I would recommend adding  an attribute for cypress such as```data-cy="element I want to select"```. This will make your cypress tests easier to write and more robust

Answer (score 3):

You can apply a `.filter()` to the parents

```js
cy.get('.market-template-2-columns')
  .filter((index,element) => element.children.length >= 3)
  .first()    
  .children()
```

Or with jQuery pseudo-selectors

```js
cy.get('.market-template-2-columns')
  .filter(':has(button:eq(3))')        
  .first()    
  .children()
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use the jQuery `nth-child` selector. If you use `nth-child(3)`, that will only select something that has more than two, you can then select the parent of that selection and get the first matching group using `eq(0)`. Then get all the buttons with `find`

```js
cy.get(".market-template-2-columns .market-button:nth-child(3)").parent(0).eq(0)

// or, to get the child buttons
cy.get(".market-template-2-columns .market-button:nth-child(3)").parent(0).eq(0).find(".market-button")

// or using tags instead of classes
cy.get("div button:nth-child(3)").parent(0).eq(0).find("button")
```